# Inconsistent region plot?

Tags: regions, inequalities

If I do a region plot of the following inequality,

```
RegionPlot[(4 - y^2)^2 ((8 + y^2) - 18 x y + 9 x^2) > 
36 (1 - y^2) ((4 + y^2) - 8 x y + (4 + y^2) x^2) && x >= y, {x, 0, 
1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Mathematica plots a region where it is valid:

[image: soln_exists].

However, if I change `x >=y` to `x>y` inside the `RegionPlot` command, the region vanishes altogether. I know that the diagonal line is `x=y`, but there clearly is a finite region where `x>y` is true and Mathematica does not displays that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to increase the number of plot points [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot) uses:

```
inequalities = (4-y^2)^2 ((8+y^2)-18 x y+9 x^2)>36 (1-y^2) ((4+y^2)-8 x y+(4+y^2) x^2) && x> y;
RegionPlot[
    inequalities,
    {x,0,1},
    {y,0,1},
    PlotPoints->100
]
```

[image]

You could also use region functionality:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[inequalities, {x, y}];
DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But why the option `plot points` matter for showing the existence of the region? this seems to be quite dangerous, to be honest! Or, is this a standard feature. Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: Also, is there any other important matter that I should be aware of before plotting regions? Anyway to crosscheck? This time I got suspicious because I randomly checked x=0.9 and y=0.89 and found it to be consistent!